# determine if a word is an isogram

Tags: python

I wrote a python code that checks if a word is an isogram. If it is an isogram, it should return ('word', True) but if it isn't an isogram, it should return ('word', False). But whenever I pass an argument like 'heavenlly', I get ('heavenlly', True) instead for ('heavenlly', False). Please I'll really appreciate your help

Here is my code:

```
def isogram(aWord):
    if aWord == '':
        return (aWord, False)
    elif type(aWord) != str:
        raise TypeError('Argument should be a string')
    else:
        for letter in aWord:
            if aWord.count(letter) > 1:
                return (aWord, False)
            else:
                return (aWord, True)
```

Comment: Should "noon" return True or False?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code only checks the first letter (in the example 'h') and then already returns. You should only return after running the entire for-loop:

```
def isogram(aWord):
    if aWord == '':
        return (aWord, False)
    elif type(aWord) != str:
        raise TypeError('Argument should be a string')
    else:
        for letter in aWord:
            if aWord.count(letter) > 1:
                return (aWord, False)
        return (aWord, True)
```

Comment: returning `if aWord.count(letter) > 1` is still semantically incorrect. "aaabbb" is an isogram.

Comment: What is your definition of "isogram"? I'm pretty sure the standard definition is that no letter of the alphabet appears more than once.

Comment: That's interesting. I looked at the german wikipedia page for the definition and it says that all letters must appear an equal amount of time. The english wikipedia page says that a letter must appear exactly once (or not at all). According to the latter definition, your code is correct. I removed my answer. By the way, this can be done in O(n), your code runs in O(n^2) because of all the counting inside the loop. Regardless, you fixed OP's code.

Answer (score 3):

See the answer by xjcl for an approach to fixing  your code.

If your definition of an isogram is that no letter may appear more than once, you can just issue

```
len(set(word)) == len(word)
```

If your definition of an isogram is that all letters appear an equal amount of times, then using a `Counter` object from the `collections` module will do the job.

```
>>> len(set(Counter('aabbcc').values())) == 1
True
>>> len(set(Counter('aabbcca').values())) == 1
False
```

The downside of this quick oneliner is that the `Counter` keeps counting even if the definition of an isogram can no longer be fulfilled (it looks at all the characters).

Comment: I only wished the accepted answer would update to an `O(n)` version, as it would then hold some pro vs. the `Counter` approach, allowing short-circuiting for non-isogram "words" (useful in case they were to be extremely long).

Comment: @dfri indeed. Since `Counter` is implemented in Python it still has the `for` loop's OOP-overhead. So rolling your own short-circuit might actually improve performance for long words.

Comment: Why not `len(set(word)) == len(word)` so we can do away with the `Counter`?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Thanks. My starting point was definition 2 and then I overlooked the very simple counter-less solution when adjusting for definition 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_isogram(word):
    if len(set(word.lower())) == len(word.lower()):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

You have to make sure Upper and Lower case are being considered!